# How to handle error while trying to open an app with location href

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to open an app with the `window.location.href`, I want to open it or if it fails, I want to download the app. This system is used by many software such as Zoom. When i click the button to open the app, if it is not installed, the console gives me this error:

> ```
> Failed to launch 'x://x because the scheme does not have a registered handler.
> ```

If I `catch` this error, I can try to download the app, but I don't know how to `catch` this. I try to `catch` this it is not catching this error. When I try with `window.open` or `window.location.href` nothing is working.

Comment: Are you sure it is an error and not an error message? The difference is that error message is just text that tells you what the error but the error is an actual error that can be caught. If it is an error message, it has to be checked with simple `if/else`

Comment: Instead of putting `x` before `://`, try using https and the app's domain instead. If the app has registered the URL, it'll catch it and open. However it depends entirely on the app how to best approach this, and this information is missing here.

Comment: @SPARTACUS5329 When i use and if, allways pass the if as true, it's an error message but it psas the if

Comment: @ChrisG There is not a domain, it 's an electron app installed on the windows client of the user.

Comment: So this electron app registers a URL scheme handler?

Comment: No, becuase is not installed, i want that it this return that message, i want to download the app to him @ChrisG

Comment: You cannot do this. Zoom does this by installing a small server, this way the website can send a request to `http://localhost:some_port/whatever`. The website can also check if the server is running by catching the request. You can in theory do this with your Electron app.